# image resize affects every image in folder

Tags: asp.net

I am having many webpages and I am using images in every page.I have one folder in my asp.net website.And I have stored my images in that folder.But my problem is when I change width and height of one image then this width and height automatically get applicable to other images that I used in webpages. I tried to change width and height of every image and saved it in aspx file but it didn't work.I am not getting what is the problem.please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Resize Image of every folder or single folder ?

for getting an idea:
plz visit :
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-resize-size-image-without-losing.html
or
http://www.dotnethelpers.com/Ultimate_Image_Resizer/AspDotNet_Sample